# HTML Domain and Path

Tags: html, url

I was learning about HTML domains and paths in my computer-science class. However, I have a question. What happens if you only specify a domain, such as `apple.com` instead of specifying a path? Does the page automatically give you the index file or something?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That entirely depends on what the web server is configured to do. What you’re doing is you’re requesting *a URL* from a *web server* via HTTP. That does not inherently have anything to do with files. The web server can respond to the request in any way it wants.

But yes, *most typically* the average web server will look for a file named something like `index.html` in its webroot folder and return it.

Answer (score 1):

yes, there is the default file that is returned if no path is provided

From [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/getting-started.html#content) documentation

> Typically, a document called index.html will be served when a directory is requested without a file name being specified. For example, if DocumentRoot is set to /var/www/html and a request is made for http://www.example.com/work/, the file /var/www/html/work/index.html will be served to the client.

From [IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/defaultdocument/) documentation:

> Default documents are enabled by default, and IIS 7 defines the following default document files in the ApplicationHost.config file as server-wide defaults: Default.htm, Default.asp, Index.htm, Index.html, Iisstart.htm.
>   (If you install ASP.NET on your Web server, the installation process will add the Default.aspx file to this list.)